# PHP extension upgrade while upgrading PHP core?

Tags: php

I need to upgrade PHP from PHP 5.3 to 5.5. So I need to know while upgrading this, Do I also need to upgrade the PHP extensions like php.xml? Which depends on PHP 5.3.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you do need to upgrade everything.

Comment: @zerkms It depends. The binary interface to the extension hasn't changed since PHP5.3. For many extensions it should work without updating the extension. PHP will check compatibility when loading the extension. However, the extension itself might have been further developed since times of PHP 5.3, therefore it makes definitely sense to upgrade them.

Comment: Any steps to upgrade this extensions explicitly? or any links where  i can find steps to upgrade the php extensions?